# Difference in I/O traffic behavior while hosting on IISExpress vs Service fabric cluster. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-service-fabric, iis-express

On my .net core Web api I'm consuming several Azure SDKs like storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc.

During development, just while I'm ***deploying*** the app on IISexpress via Visual studio 2017 I can able to see (via Fiddler) many HTTP **handshaking** calls going to corresponding Azure resource urls. Attaching one sample traffic captured by fiddler while deploying the app on IIS express.

```
               A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

            Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
            Random: 60 6C 73 5C 37 CD D8 F9 FC FA 9C A9 D2 BE F8 1D A7 09 39 7D 62 8D 9F FC D6 4F 02 75 78 95 53 39
            "Time": 2/25/2019 9:47:36 AM
            SessionID: empty
            Extensions: 
                server_name mystorage.table.core.windows.net
                supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
                ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
                signature_algs  rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
                SessionTicket   empty
                extended_master_secret  empty
                renegotiation_info  00
```

But while hosting on my local Service Fabric cluster I **can't** able to see  via Fiddler the internal/**handshaking** http calls (like mentioned above) made to Azure resource like storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc.

Why is the "internal/**handshaking**  http calls made to Azure resource storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc" made by application **not** visible in fiddler while hosting on local Service fabric cluster but it is visible while hosting on IISExpress? this understanding required to understanding the below behaviour of the application

On my appsettings.config, if I have provided dummy connection string for Azure storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc while hosting on IISExpress, ***entire*** application crashes because all **handshaking**  http calls made to Azure resource storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc are failing. While loading the same application with same dummy connection strings to Azure resources on local service fabric cluster, it works as expected no issues as such ***atleast*** on those functionalities which are not using  storage table, blob, Azure Key vault etc.

If we deploy application on PRODUCTION Azure service fabric cluster while Azure storage account outage happens, Out of these different behaviors(between IISExpress/service fabric cluster) which is the one to be expected to happen in real time? to mitigate it.

Comment: This is probably related to the fact that your local cluster is hosted in containers

Comment: @JasonP, can bit elaborate please? what happens if it hosted in containers. I'm using Microsoft Service Fabric SDK v4.1.416.9590 to create local Service Fabric Cluster to do development & testing. Does it uses containers internally?